# Remove old url after redirect .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

After redirect 301 i have a problem.

```
Redirect 301 /en/aesthetic-procedures /en/for-patients
```

goes to

```
/en/for-patients?/en/aesthetic-procedures
```

Now I wont to remove "?/en/aesthetic-procedures" and simply looks like `/en/for-patients`

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for helping me.

There is more from from .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(index\.php)?\?([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=301,NC,NE]
IndexOptions +HTMLTable +FancyIndexing

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine OnRedirect 301 /en/aesthetic-procedures /en/for-patients
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the actual URL you are requesting? `Redirect` does prefix-based matching and appends any excess to the target URL, but that would not explain why parts of the original URL would end up in the query string here. Do you have more going on in your .htaccess, any additional internal request rewriting using mod_rewrite maybe?

Comment: Yes! Added more to post.

Comment: Try and put the `Redirect` at the very top, before everything else. (And why did you wrap that in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and preface it with `RewriteEngine On`? `Redirect` is not part of mod_rewrite to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I removed <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and put the Redirect at the very top. The first row now is Redirect 301 /en/aesthetic-procedures /en/for-patients but the result is the same. :(